# Inline location.href javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to have an inline javascript link that looks like this without an onClick (for example)

```
<a href="javascript:location.href=('http://www.google.com')">Google</a>
```

Is something like this possible? If so, how can I make it work?

The javascript must be inline harcoded like this, because my CMS does not allow me to do append "#example" at the end of URLs for anchors, for example, so I'd like to have an inline javascript so I can link this way, which the CMS allows this type of format believe it or not.

Comment: Does the example in your question not work? It looks fine to me.

Comment: Which CMS? I believe you should make a question about how to make that functionality in your CMS rather than using such ugly hacks that will force basic browsing functionality to depend on JS.

Comment: yes. its a hack. but its all i got :(